# How to type in the file explorer using PyWinAuto

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, pywinauto

I am trying to write a web scraper in python that uploads a file to a website (through a dashboard). To upload a file, I need to click on this box.

[image: File upload box]

When I click on this box it opens a File Explorer window. I want to be able to type into the 'File Name:' box.

[image: Windows file explorer]
I assume it's possible with PyWinAuto but I have never used it before and have no idea how I'm supposed to go about it. The furthest I've got is connecting to the window

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe", title="Open")
```

Comment: Are you sure to be connected to the good window? I think it is the taskbar
Try app.top_window().draw_outline()
To easily do what you want to do try Pywinauto recorder

Comment: Do you know how i can target the file explorer window?

Comment: Please post your solution as answer and mark it as accepted. It's better signal for others the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: Well done! Vasily is right: posting your solution as an answer and also adding the method by which you found the solution would certainly be of great help to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out in the end.

Instead of connecting to 'explorer.exe', I had to connect to the browser window that contained the file explorer box using this code.

```
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Browser window name',timeout=100)

fileBox = app.BrowserWindowName.child_window(title="File name:", auto_id="1148", control_type="Edit").wrapper_object()
```

This targeted the 'File Name:' box that I was then able to send a file path to by using the type_keys() method

```
fileBox.type_keys('pathToFile', with_spaces=True)
```

Comment: set_text() would be a more reliable method instead of type_keys()

Comment: @VidyaMarathe not only reliable but is also faster method.